# Добавить плавность анимации на Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, анимация

Всем привет!

Есть следующая часть кода:

```
(function () {
var img = document.createElement('IMG');
img.src = "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/08/06/19/23/bull-1575005_960_720.jpg";

var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var cw = c.width = 4040;
var ch = c.height = 1000;

ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)';

var framesPerSecond = 5;

function animate() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        // animating/drawing code goes here
        drawShape();
        drawImg();

    }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function drawShape() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch); // clear canvas
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(811.1, 780.3); //start
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(618.7 + generateCurves(), 731.5, 690.1, 757.3, 420.1, 462.29999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(150.10000000000002 + generateCurves(), 167.29999999999995, 949.1, -237.20000000000005, 1349.6, 113.29999999999995);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1490.3 + generateCurves(), 236.39999999999995, 1787.1999999999998, 261.9, 1685.6, 527.3);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1609.5 + generateCurves(), 725.9, 1544.6, 656, 1422.1, 707.3);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(1295.7 + generateCurves(), 760.2, 1174, 872.3, 811.1, 780.3);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawImg() {
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
}

function generateCurves() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1;
}})();

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

В целом должно выйти вот такое пятно - [image: требуемый результат]

У меня получается сделать лишь "подергивания", но никак не плавную анимацию.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!!!

Comment: а где тут вообще анимация? если на каждую перерисовку просто рисуется новая картинка

Comment: к тому и вопрос - у меня все рывками делается. я только такой способ пока что придумал. хотелось бы получить совет - как сделать чтобы все было плавно...

Comment: нужно сделать маленькие шаги для переходов, возможно хватит простого уменьшения изменения с 60, до каких-нибудь 2-5

Answer (score 1):

```
var framesPerSecond = 5;
setTimeout(function() {
    /* ... */
}, 1000 / framesPerSecond);
```

У Вас получается прорисовка происходит раз в 200 миллисекунд. Уменьшите этот параметр до 50 миллисекунд.

Comment: как уменьшение интервала может добавить анимацию?

Comment: В таком случае все слишком быстро мигает) Мне такой вариант не подходит. Но спасибо за предложение!

Comment: @ЕвгенийБредюк ну вы меньше делайте за каждый шаг. Как Вы можете добавить плавность не уменьшив шага анимации?